# perl anonymous subroutine within a named subroutine

Tags: perl

Regarding below code, how does $one_sub and $two_sub become coderef's to the anonymous subroutines within named sub "sup"? The named sub isn't 'returning' those two anon subs; or is it? (at least I haven't put such a statement).

```
sub sup {

          my $neh = sub {
                  say "this is 'neh' subroutine"
          };

          my $hen = sub {
                  say "this is 'hen' subroutine"
         };
          ($neh, $hen);
  }

  my ($one_sub, $two_sub) = &sup;
```

Using Data::Dumper::Streamer show's :

```
$CODE1 = sub {
           use warnings;
           use strict;
           no feature;
           use feature ':5.10';
           say q[this is 'neh' subroutine];
         };
$CODE1 = sub {
           use warnings;
           use strict;
           no feature;
           use feature ':5.10';
           say q[this is 'hen' subroutine];
         };
```

Comment: [`perldoc -f return`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/return.html): "In the absence of an explicit `return`, a subroutine, `eval`, or `do FILE` automatically returns the value of the last expression evaluated."

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot should probably be an answer.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why explicit returns are a good thing :)

Comment: Tip: Don't prefix sub calls using `&`. That means "ignore any prototype on the sub". Unless that's what you meant to do, of course.

Comment: Also makes some potentially rather interesting unexpected behaviour when you pass through and tamper with `@_`.

Answer (score 8):

To quote [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html):

> If no `return` is found and if the last statement is an expression, its value is returned.

`($neh, $hen);` is an expression.  In list context, its value is the 2 anonymous subs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is returning:

```
 ($neh, $hen);
```

In Perl the latest evaluated statement is returned. You don't need to explicitly call:

```
 return ($neh, $hen);
```

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/return.html